# Is it possible to consume ArcGIS Hosted Table into local or ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-online

I would like to publish a table to our ArcGIS Online (AGOL) organization account.

Is it possible to consume hosted features in AGOL to a local db or ArcSDE database connection?

By consume I mean import a hosted ArcGIS Online table into a geodatabase with ArcPy.

By local db, I mean file geodatabase

Comment: By what do you mean "consume"?  Any data can always be loaded in a myriad of ways, but some of those ways are easier than others.  Please edit the question to expound on the desired process.

Comment: What do you mean by a "local db"?  Do you mean a file geodatabase?

Comment: @Geoffrey West: I got the same error. I think it is caused by an empty dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a quick [read of this blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/10/quick-tips-consuming-feature-services-with-geoprocessing/). It lays the ground work for what you want to do. You just need to replace FeatureSet with RecordSet.

The following code uses a featureservice, and brings down the items as a table -- you keep saying table, so I assume you're talking items *without* geometry. If you actually mean features, change the returnGeo field to True, and then flip RecordSet to FeatureSet, and CopyRows to CopyFeatures

```
import arcpy

FSURL = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/2/"

where = "1=1"
fields = "reinforced, speed, countrycode, staffcomment"
returnGeo = False
token = ''

query = "query?where={0}&outFields={1}&returnGeometry={2}&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&f=json&token={3}".format(
where, fields, returnGeo, token)

url = FSURL + query
rs = arcpy.RecordSet()
rs.load(url)

arcpy.CopyRows_management(rs, r"c:\temp\f.gdb\fsTable")
```

Modify the query, where clause and fields to match what you want to copy local from **your** featureservice.

Comment: Kevin, will this work with the secured (non-public) AGOL hosted service? You need to provide username and password. I read that you can provide token, but how this token should be generated?

Comment: You'll have to obtain a token to work with a secured service. Theres a code example to obtain a token here: https://github.com/arcpy/AutomaticUpdatesIntoFeatureService/blob/master/UpdatePointFromExternalAPI.py#L45-L63

Comment: This is a good start, but based on network connectivity, this script must leverage AGOL, and not  ArcGIS Server for a hosted table.  The ideal workflow would to have a constituent enter a table each day and a script then consumes this AGOL hosted table into a local file geodatabase or ArcSDE database.

Comment: Its the same difference. Replace the URL in the code sample with the one to a hosted feature service on AGOL.

Comment: I see, when I try this, this error returns.  

`RuntimeError: RecordSetObject: Cannot open table for Load`

Answer (score 1):

@ Alex Tereshenkov

Please see this script which takes into account the token generation for AGOL hosted features.

```
import arcpy
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

gtUrl = 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken'
gtValues = {'username' : 'yourUserName',
'password' : 'YourPassWord',
'referer' : 'http://www.arcgis.com',
'f' : 'json' }
gtData = urllib.urlencode(gtValues)
gtRequest = urllib2.Request(gtUrl, gtData)
gtResponse = urllib2.urlopen(gtRequest)
gtJson = json.load(gtResponse)
gtToken = gtJson['token']

FSURL = "http://services1.arcgis.com/X1hcdGx5Fxqn4d0j/ArcGIS/rest/services/aService/FeatureServer/0/"
#last back slash is necessary

where = "1=1"
fields = "NUMBERCYLA, NAME"
returnGeo = False
token = gtToken

print token

query = "query?where={0}&outFields={1}&returnGeometry={2}&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&f=json&token={3}".format(
where, fields, returnGeo, token)


url = FSURL + query

rs = arcpy.RecordSet()
rs.load(url)
arcpy.CopyRows_management(rs, r"c:\rest_test\rest_test.gdb\fsTable")
```